# Using decimal in keys of YAML file

Tags: symfony

I am trying to make a YAML file like this -

```
my_scores:
    1: 1.2
    0.5: 1.1
    0.4: 0.45
    0.2: 0.44
    0.1: 0.15
    0.08: 0.14
    0.04: 0.13
```

but YAML is not reading keys which have decimal. Any workaround for this?

I am using symfony2 and parsing like this `Yaml::parse('path_to_file')`

Comment: You should probably state which language and possibly which library you are using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML specification allows you to specify your keys as [quoted keys using double quotes](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2787109):

```
my_scores:
    "1": 1.2
    "0.5": 1.1
    "0.4": 0.45
    "0.2": 0.44
    "0.1": 0.15
    "0.08": 0.14
    "0.04": 0.13
```

Update:

Maybe some parsers could read and process content as you shown it, but if yours can't, quoting the keys is a way of a workaround. Another thing you should do is to read keys as strings. If you want to treat them as floats, read them as strings and convert to floats before further processing (e.g. before comparison).

Comment: I want the keys as float values as they are used for comparison

Answer (score 0):

Load yml file like this:

```
scores = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/scores.yml")
    p scores
    => {"my_scores"=>{1=>1.2, 0.5=>1.1, 0.4=>0.45, 0.2=>0.44, 0.1=>0.15, 0.08=>0.14, 0.04=>0.13}}
```

Comment: I am using symfony and parsing it like this                                                            Yaml::parse("path_to_file")

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by PHP truncating [floats that are keys for arrays to integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-56):

> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> ...
>
> Floats are also cast to integers, which means that the fractional part will be truncated. E.g. the key 8.7 will actually be stored under 8.

Your example is correct YAML. There should be no need to quote your floats and make them into strings to get this YAML to load. So maybe you should consider switching to a less restrictive environment to process this data.

In Python (disclaimer: I am the author of ruamel.yaml, but the older PyYAML works as well):

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """
my_scores:
    1: 1.2
    0.5: 1.1
    0.4: 0.45
    0.2: 0.44
    0.1: 0.15
    0.08: 0.14
    0.04: 0.13
"""
print(ruamel.yaml.safe_load(yaml_str))
```

gives:

```
{'my_scores': {0.5: 1.1, 1: 1.2, 0.08: 0.14, 0.2: 0.44, 0.4: 0.45, 0.1: 0.15, 0.04: 0.13}}
```